# I am searching for the datasheet of the TA7634AP

Tags: integrated-circuit, oscillator

I am unable to locate the datasheet for the Toshiba TA7634AP.

This is an IC from an Olivetti M24 monitor from 1986.

It should be a horizontal and vertical oscillator meaning that it generates pulses.

Without the datasheet it will be impossible to check if it is at fault.

Comment: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.* - unfortunately, this includes "can't find, can you help" questions. I did have a quick look and it does appear not to be found anywhere.

Comment: Check with these guys : https://www.sierraic.com/buy_online/datasheet/TA7634AP or here : http://transparentc.com/parts/TA7634AP

Comment: @Andyaka that was my initial reaction, too. Can I copy/paste your comment as answer to https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/how-to-deal-with-datasheet-requests ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sure you can. You can even call me a moron if you want but, be nice about it LOL.

Comment: @Andyaka nothing would be further from what I consider you to be! (also, I agree, I just tried to not push my personal opinion too hard in that question on Meta)